# Why might .exists be returning false in Firestore, even if a document does exist?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to check if a document exists in Firestore - if it already exists, I want to return so that I don't duplicate the entry. I've followed the directions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), which has also been referenced in other answers, but as I step through the program I see "exists" always set to false. As a result, each time this code executes, there is a duplicate entry added. Is there anything I can try to figure out why exists is not set to true when the entry does already exist?

Thanks so much!

```
    var docRef = db.collection('collection-testing').doc(docName);
    
    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
     let exists = doc.exists;
     if (exists) {
      return;
     }
    });

/* Loads new entry below*/
```

Comment: Is the rest of your code inside the `.then` callback? or where your comment is?

Comment: Have you tried adding any logging to see how your code is executing and what the actual values of the variables are at each point?  It's probably not doing at all what you expect in the order that you expect it.  The code at your comment is going to run before the database query completes with a callback to your then() callback.

Comment: Thank you. To respond to Nicholas, the rest of my code is below the comment "Loads new entry below". To respond to Doug, I used a breakpoint on "exists" and saw that it was set to false, even when the document does exist.

Comment: I should also add that even if I put the code under the comment instead into the .then callback, the behavior is unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the issue. My document was only used to store collections, but did not have any data set to the document itself. After adding data in `.set()`, the above code now functions as expected.

Comment: This might be the answer to my version of basically the same question, where I am adding data to Firestore manually, by adding a document, giving that document an ID, and by giving that document one field of data plus a corresponding value.  For some reason, Firestore does not acknowledge the existence of that document - .exists returns false.  Must I set the data for a difference?  Why shouldn't manually placed data be counted/read?